# Why Django want to alter table with proxy model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I'm using Django 1.8, Python 2.7.15. Junior dev.

I created a model Test with many to many field to Django Group model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

I've made a migration, my project was working, all was good.

Now I had to create Group's proxy model with specyfic managers:

```
class ExtendedGroup(Group):
    get_all = AllGroupsManager()
    objects = DefaultGroupManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

And I had to change my Test model group field (is has methods that must use new managers... so I have to use ExtendedGroup):
I'm changing ManyToManyField relation from Group to ExtendedGroup.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(ExtendedGroup)
```

ExtendedGroup is proxy model so I think Test's group field should be related to Group even if I use ExtendedGroup (becouse it is proxy model).

But when I run server I got ProgrammingError:

> column test_test_group.extendedgroup_id does not exist

When I "makemigrations" I can see that Django want to Alter group field with new relation to model (ExtendedGroup) that actually does not have any tables in database becouse it is proxy model.

```
operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='test',
            name='group',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='mainpage.ExtendedGroup'),
        ),
    ]
```

What is going here? Is it right? Why Django want to create relation to model that does not have any tables?

I just don't understand it.

I will appreciate any help!

EDIT:
When I run migration (migrate) I get a bunch of errors:

> AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute
>   'm2m_reverse_field_name'

So it does not work :(

Comment: I am not sure if `ForeignKey`s to proxy models are supported. Perhaps this is just the ForeignKey relation that "assumes" it refers to a real model, and thus has the impression it has to construct such relation.

Comment: I think you are right and it is not supported. I updated my question. Just after running a migration I got an error "AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_reverse_field_name'"

Comment: Probably there is no way to repair it ?

Comment: What is your goal here? What do you expect to be the benefit of pointing a foreign key to a proxy model instead of the base model?

Comment: @HåkenLid I run into the same issue. My goal was to have custom queryset methods on related field.

Comment: @Tomás: You can post a new question about your issue and include a link to this question, if you think it might be relevant. The first comment here by Willem explains the error, but it's hard to suggest a solution without more information. This is what's sometimes called  "the XY problem"

Comment: ForeignKeys to proxy models are supported by Django (although I don't believe it's well documented), and the reverse relationship handling was improved in 1.10, as evidenced by this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18012, however I'm unsure about ManyToManyFields. I see a similar error with m2m fields currently in Django 2.2.

Comment: same here... when I moved 'tag' field to an umbrella application and created ManyToMany references, it actually worked for every app but not for the one I have moved the field from. Though, server runs fine, and even data is being handled properly... Considering leaving it for now, since it is still working...